# What causes MAMP download php files instead of running them?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, localhost, mamp

Having built a few different sites on MAMP recently, I have an intermittent problem where the site is working fine but sometimes if I install a plugin, no matter what page I visit on my localhost installed site, it starts to download the pages rather than display them. The only way I have managed to get the site working again is to completely reinstall it, but if I try installing the plugin again the issue repeats.

If anyone knows the cause or fix for this I would be most grateful!

Comment: Problem with the plugin(s) or adding it messes up the PHP configuration in Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Do you know if locally hosted sites more susceptible to this issue of PHP configuration being messed up in Apache? Are there any settings I can change to remedy this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, MAMP once installed is functionnal, a set of minimal working configuration is provided.  You could compare changes between your configuration and the default files.